# NuGet Pack -Build does not seem to understand c# 6.0

Tags: c#, nuget, c#-6.0

I have just went through one of my projects and used a bunch of the new c# 6 features like the null propagation operator `handler?.Invoke(null, e)`, which builds in Visual Studio.  However, when I run my script to publish out the NuGet packages, I get compilation errors saying:

```
EventName.cs(14,66): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'
EventName.cs(69,68): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
EventName.cs(69,74): error CS1520: Method must have a return type
```

It would appear NuGet is using an older version of the compiler, but I was wondering if anyone knew a work around or configuration that could be set to resolve the issue.

Comment: NuGet shouldn't be compiling anything. My guess would be that the issue is in your script.

Comment: @svick The script has remained unchanged, the only change was using c# 6.0 features.  Please feel free to check the script itself but its simply calling the nuget CLI - https://github.com/G3N7/LAN.Core.Eventing/blob/master/NugetBuild.cmd

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the `-Build` option (and somehow missed it in your title). I think a workaround would be not to use that.

Comment: @Gent did you manage to find a solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @niaher please see accepted answer for the link to the github issue.  It has now been resolved and will be released shortly I am sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have also found this bug in the Nuget which is still not resolved:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1107

You can use the following workaround:

1. Modify the script to build your project using correct version of MSBuild - just call `MSBuild.exe` yourself, supply the path to the csproj or sln file and build your project in a correct configuration yourself.
2. Create a nuspec file that describes your package (https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference). You can use the Nuget Package Explorer app. Use DLLs produced in step 1.
3. Use `nuget pack mypackage.nuspec` to build the package.

Comment: The aforementioned Github issue has now been resolved, you can now specificity which version of MSBuild to use.  Thank you very much for this information!